# Why is the sorted insert not working properly?

Tags: python, class, linked-list

Here is the code for a linked list. When applying the following commands, it doesn't work properly.

The output is inconsistent.

The class is defined below.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data) -> None:
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
    

class linkedList:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.head=None
    
    def insert(self,data):
        if self.head==None:
            self.head=Node(data)
        else:
            temp=self.head
            self.head=Node(data)
            self.head.next=temp
     
        
    def sortedInsert(self,data):
        if self.head==None:
            self.head=Node(data)
        else:
            if self.head.data>data:
                self.insert(data)
            else:
                cur=self.head
                while data>cur.data and cur.next!=None:
                    cur=cur.next
                temp=cur.next
                cur.next=Node(data)
                cur.next.next=temp
                
    def __str__(self):
        st=""
        cur=self.head
        if self.head==None:
            print("Empty")
        else:
            while cur.next!=None:
                st+=str(cur.data)+" -> "
                cur=cur.next
            st+=str(cur.data)
            return st
a=linkedList() 
a.sortedInsert(10) 
a.sortedInsert(20) 
a.sortedInsert(5) 
a.sortedInsert(30)

a.sortedInsert(5) 
a.sortedInsert(1) 
a.sortedInsert(18) 
print(a)
```

The method sortedInsert works for some cases and not for others. Can someone debug it?

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with DSA (digital signature algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are going to far in your while loop:

```
while data>cur.data and cur.next!=None:
```

You leave this loop when your `cur` is smaller, so you want to put new element between `cur` and the previous one. But you use **his** next. Change it to:

```
while cur.next!=None and cur.next.data < data:
```